# Html.RouteLink href null despite route (seeming) to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a route (which works):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Details", // Route name
    "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Advisors", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new { id = new GuidConstraint() } // Constraint
);
```

And a link:

```
@Html.RouteLink(@item.FullName, "Details", new { controller = "Advisors", id = item.Id })
```

However the link is rendering as:

```
<a href="">David Wick</a>
```

Basically my goal here is to have routes that are `{controller}/{id}` and the links rendered are also in that format.  When using `Html.ActionLink()` links render as `{controller}/{action}/{id}` and `Html.RenderRoute()` doesn't seem to work at all, despite the route working.

What's going on here?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, so it's mildly freaky that you asked this today. :) ::waits for answer::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to correct this issue just now by changing "item.Id" to "item.Id.ToString()". Probably not the ideal solution, but good enough for me for now.

Comment: one thing to note: you can use `Html.ActionLink()` and it'll render as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (I think) and it was actually the route constraint that was failing because the IRouteConstraint was checking for

```
routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest
```

whereas the RouteLink HTML helper will actually produce

```
routeDirection == RouteDirection.UrlGeneration
```